# Tree-View LINKING in Doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen, doxywizard

In DOXYGEN, initially before Generate_TreeView is checked (i.e, when disabled), when I click on the side function choosing pane, I get the correct documentation of the function. But after Generate_TreeView is checked and when clicked on any function to view its corresponding documentation it shows the File reference instead of documentation. One thing to be noted is : I am generating separate member pages for all the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution !! Make sure you have checked "SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES" in DOXY-Wizard !! I had the following issue in DOYGEN 1.8.4 but once I started using DOXYGEN 1.8.7, the issue got resolved !! Just a version issue !!